# How can I start a .bat script (CMD) with javascript

Tags: javascript, batch-file, cmd

How to run a `.bat script` (CMD) with javascript?
I would like to start bash scripts through a web site.

Comment: To be clear, do you want a [tag:batch-file], _.bat_, to be run via [tag:javascript]? or do you want [tag:javascript] to be run from a [tag:batch-file], _.bat_. Also please note that StackOverflow is not a code request service, here you provide the code you've written and tried but which fails to work as expected, and we help you to fix it. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58133493/edit) to include that code and confirm your exact requirements. Also, if you want JavaScript to run a `.bat` file then for security reasons, that is not permitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could link the .bat with a simple `<a href>` and set your browser-specific settings to automatically execute all files of type .bat instead of downloading them.

I'm afraid auto-executing anything on a computer isn't possible through JS for security reasons.